# What is a good word to describe someone who is talking down to you and thinks your decisions/actions are wrong?

Tags: single-word-requests

So if someone is giving you an attitude when you are telling them about certain life decisions you made.  And that person really doesn't understand the situation, not to mention they are ignorant... how would you describe what he or she is being?

Comment: To summarise, this someone is 1) talking down to you, 2) thinks your actions are wrong, 3) does not understand the situation, 4) is ignorant?

Comment: And 5) giving you an attitude?

Comment: Informally, "mansplaining" is condescendingly explaining something you already know, often better than them, under the misguided assumption that you're ignorant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you call someone who thinks everyone is incompetent](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259004/what-do-you-call-someone-who-thinks-everyone-is-incompetent-doesnt-know-anythi/261945#261945)

Answer (score 3):

With regards to talking down, a possible word is **patronising**

> treat with an apparent kindness which betrays a feeling of superiority.
>
> She's a good-hearted girl,’ he said in a patronizing voice

or **condescending**

> having or showing an attitude of patronizing superiority.
>
> An example of condescending is a parent who speaks to her grown child as if he were still a toddler.

Comment: Unless they're in the US, in which case, they'd be patronizing.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answer above, "patronizing," or "condescending," and would add 
"dismissive," which might be a good alternative as it describes the same thing but without as much attitude attached.  This means it might be a good word to use if you are trying to be diplomatic while still describing "patronizing and condescending."  A fine point, but fine points are useful sometimes :)